# Kubernetes ignores config.json while doing docker pull

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to pull an image from private registry and I have the auth stored in /root/.docker/config.json in a kubernetes cluster node. 
I have also verified that the auth works as expected while pulling the docker image.

```sh
curl -v \
     -X GET \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /tmp/auth_bearer.txt)" repo-url/manifests/latest \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
```

Response:

```sh
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 23:27:09 GMT <
Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json <
Content-Length: 3455 < Connection: keep-alive < Vary: Origin <
opc-request-id: 772f679098749bb474d59161 < Docker-Content-Digest:
sha256:17dcbbf7c670d8894ddfefc2907c9f045bfc45e60954525635632abbf02910
< {    "schemaVersion": 2,    "mediaType":
"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",    "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
      "size": 9504,
      "digest": "sha256:d59db4a22d6ba8f1d3b5d7c8f8f410688dee569a947bf242e6c3e3b708f634829"
},    "layers": [
      { [...]
```

From the above response, it is clear that I have the image present at the private repo location and the auth is correct. However when I try to do `docker pull <repo-url>/image-name:image-tag` I get this error:

```
Trying to pull repository <repo-url>/image-name:image-tag ... 
pull access denied for <repo-url>/image-name:image-tag, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?
Why is the node ignoring docker credentials stored at /root/.docker/config.json?

Comment: Why would you do that? Why not apply deployment yaml and pass auths as secret?

Comment: I do not want to use imagePullSecrets since there's an external service that is managing my image in private registry and updating the docker creds in my .docker/config.json every 20 minutes.

Comment: I assume it also doesn't work with Kubelet and you aren't just testing with `docker pull`? Because that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use file based config**

According to the documentation there is the following option: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry

You can set the docker secrets in a file listed here:

- `{--root-dir:-/var/lib/kubelet}/config.json`
- `{cwd of kubelet}/config.json`
- `${HOME}/.docker/config.json`
- `/.docker/config.json`
- `{--root-dir:-/var/lib/kubelet}/.dockercfg`
- `{cwd of kubelet}/.dockercfg`
- `${HOME}/.dockercfg`
- `/.dockercfg`

> Note: You may have to set HOME=/root explicitly in your environment file for kubelet.

Comment: I do not want to use imagePullSecrets since there's an external service that is managing my image in private registry and updating the docker creds in my .docker/config.json every 20 minutes.

Comment: @user4202236 please have a look at my updated answer. I guess this is what you need.